# Nested Dictionary Manipulation

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary in this structure:

```
dictionary = {chapter: {section: {sub_section: {'a':{...}, 'b':{...}, 'c':{...}, 'd':{...}, 'e':{...}}}}}
```

Assume chapter, section, sub_section are values of list variables.

For every possible combination, key values 'a,b,c,d,e' are same.

I want 'c' dictionary to contain 'c','d','e' dictionaries.

How to convert the dictionary to the new dictionary?

```
new_dict = {chapter: {section: {sub_section: {'a':{...}, 'b':{...}, 'c':{ 'c':{...}, 'd':{...}, 'e'={...}}}}}}
```

If possible less label or name based, more index or level based approach is appreciated.

Comment: could you clarify your last sentence? what do you mean by index? Dictionaries don't have indices, no?

Comment: I added that because I may be missing something. Since chapter, section, sub_section variables have many elements and entering dict.get.get.get... takes more work; I am searching for a level based method. Because levels are same every time. But you are correct, I did not hear index in dict .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of the whole nested dictionary. Then copy the c, d, e elements into the new dictionary's `c` element, and delete the unnecessary `d` and `e` elements.

```
from copy import deepcopy

new_dict = deepcopy(dictionary)
ss = new_dict['chapter']['section']['subsection']
ss['c'] = {key: ss[key] for key in ['c', 'd', 'e']}
for key in ['d', 'e']:
    del ss[key]
```

You say you don't want this to be label based, but I don't see any logic that can be used to select the elements to be moved without just listing the labels.